# file_get_contents stopped working, returning an empty string

Tags: php, file-get-contents, string

I wrote this [script](https://github.com/AzizLight/fire) that uses `file_get_contents` extensively. But it stopped working in one place, here is the snippet in question:

```
private function patch_codeigniter_file($file_location)
{
    $this->backup_file($file_location);
    $tmp = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $file_location);
    $file_name = end($tmp);
    $file = file_get_contents($file_location);

    // ...
}
```

`file_get_contents` returns an empty string. Here are a couple of facts about the context:

- `$file_location` is an absolute path to a **local** file.
- The file that `$file_location` points to exists (yes that's a fact)
- `file_get_contents` doesn't return any errors.
- `error_reporting` is set to `-1`
- I'm on OS X Mountain Lion using the latest version of MAMP which ships with PHP 5.4.4

Does anybody know what the problem might be? Just this morning `file_get_contents` was working fine, and I tried on a Windows 7 Virtual Machine and it works fine too.

Comment: Check also: `display_errors`, `log_errors`, `error_log` (and read [the runtime configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)).

Comment: I did all that, no errors thrown: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: do `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)`

Comment: Check the *exact* return value. Is it `string(0) ""` or `bool(false)`? The former would indicate a genuinely empty file. The latter would indicate an error.

Comment: @AndreasLinden I tried that and it still doesn't give any error messages. `error_reporting(-1)` enables error reporting for ALL error types by the way.

Comment: @cbuckley `string(0) ""`, and the file became empty by magic. I'm officially an idiot for not checking that first.

Comment: haha, for sure that's your backup_file method xD

Comment: @AndreasLinden that was my first thought! [Looks OK though](https://github.com/AzizLight/fire/blob/master/classes/commands/migrate.php#L333).